# Xdebug not installed in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, centos, xdebug

I want to integrate PHP in IntelliJ IDEA but it shows Xdebug is not installed. When I am trying to install xdebug, I get the following error:

```
[root@localhost KS137]# pecl install Xdebug
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendDebugger.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendDebugger.so: undefined symbol: zend_execute_ex
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:399:0,
                 from /tmp/glibctestNDaQkR:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:10:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
downloading xdebug-2.3.2.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.3.2.tgz (266,287 bytes)
........................................................done: 266,287 bytes
74 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-KS137M2hKpn/xdebug-2.3.2
running: /var/tmp/xdebug/configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-KS137M2hKpn/xdebug-2.3.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/var/tmp/xdebug/configure' failed
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please improve your formatting and add some source from the files mentioned in the exception so that others can look into it with more ease.

Comment: Thank you Jakob for suggestion. I highlighted the errer now.. please check. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, that's much better :)

Comment: Did you notice where it says `See 'config.log' for more details`?